# r - Filtering by Rank in a df with with NAs - Not working

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, na, names

I have a df with several thousand variables that are ranked over time.  Variables as colnames, dates as rownames, and the ranks as values.

I am trying to pull the top n ranked variables from this dataframe.

My code, below, works nicely for a data frame with no NAs in its ranks, but for when there are missing data for a particular date (where instead of a rank there's an NA), it breaks:

```
top.n.variables <- apply(ranks.df, 1, function(x) names(x)[x<3])
top.n.variables <- t(top.n.variables)
top.n.variables <- as.data.frame(top.n.variables)
```

When I use this in a dataframe with NAs (which I cannot na.omit, as it distorts the dimensions of the data.frame), it returns a data frame with c(NA, NA, NA...) for each value by date, instead of the top (2 in this case) ranked variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Give an example of your data pls  :)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(ranks.df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(ranks.df, 20))`.